# Error Uploading Assets

Tags: assets

We're receiving the following error when uploading Assets:

> Upload failed for Michael-Mabry-COO-MOOYAH-executive.png. The error
>   message was: “Error uploading the file: The file
>   “/nfs/c12/h03/mnt/215595/domains/mooyah.com/html/craft/storage/runtime/temp/assets57c97ea812e213.88692692.png”
>   does not appear to be an image.”

[image]

I assumed this was a case of the client formatting the images incorrectly, but I tried it myself and they are valid image files.

Anyone come across this before?

Comment: Having the same problem!! :S http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/the-file-does-not-appear-to-be-an-image-bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you're using [GD](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) for your image processing library and the PNG is in a format that it doesn't recognize. Try installing [Imagick](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).  Craft will use it automatically if it sees it's installed and it support a much wider range of image formats.

Comment: ImageMagick appears to be installed, but Craft isn't picking it up or the server (Media Temple Grid) isn't allowing PHP to access it.

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/207470423/is-imagemagick-installed-on-the-grid#3

I don't have access to php.ini so I'm hoping I can do this through htaccess somehow?

Comment: They've got an .htaccess solution in the article you linked to?

Comment: I saw that but it doesn't provide enough detail about how to actually make it work. Any help would be great!

Comment: Open your `php.ini` file and add `open_basedir = /nfs:/tmp:/usr/local:/etc/apache2/gs-bin:/usr/bin/convert` to it. Probably best contacting MediaTemple as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on `macOS Sierra`, running on with the following installed using `homebrew`:

- Craft CMS (2.6.2989)
- nginx (1.12.1)
- php-fpm 7.1 (7.1.8)
- php71-imagick (3.4.3)

After a number of hour of digging around I found the following.

By default (don't ask me why), the configuration file for Imagick has image format configuration commented out....Thanks for that guys.

#### The Fix

Uncomment file format configurations in `/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/magic.xml`

```
<magicmap>
  <magic name="GIF" offset="0" target="GIF8"/>
  <magic name="JPEG" offset="0" target="\377\330\377"/>
  <magic name="PNG" offset="0" target="\211PNG\r\n\032\n"/>
  <magic name="TIFF" offset="0" target="\115\115\000\052"/>
</magicmap>
```

Then restart php-fpm (on macOS it was for me `brew services restart php71`)

#### Don't forget!

Once you've done the above, don't forget to run the `Update Assets Indexes` in Craft CP. This will generate all of the thumbnails for the images.

[image: Run -> Update Assets Indexes]

Hope this helps someone.