# The file does not appear to be an image. Bug?

Tags: assets, control-panel, bug

I've installed the latest ImageMagick on my ubuntu 14 server. If I force imageDriver to use 'imagick', I can only upload Gif images. And if I force it to use GD, I can upload all images but only static gif images.

[image]

The images are not changed in any programs.

It's important for me to have both options. Any ideas what this issues can be? I use php 7.0

```
Upload failed for background.jpg. The error message was: “Error uploading the file: The file “/var/www/html/craftcms/craft/storage/runtime/temp/assets57cb93709cf445.74590720.jpg” does not appear to be an image.”
```

Comment: Go to /admin/utils/phpinfo and search for "fileinfo". Do you see any references to that?

Comment: Yes I see. http://share.engbjerg.dk/PHuqsGTuCK.jpg - It't uploading gif image but only with ONE loop. :S

Comment: In case it helps others: I got this error with a client trying to upload huge animated gifs (3000 x 3750px). I guess the imagemagick resources were being exhausted. It was resolved by asking them to upload a smaller version (half the dimensions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error will occur if the fileinfo extension or imagick (ImageMagick) extension are not configured with a comprehensive list of file MIME types (the "magic file", as they refer to it, I think), or the images you're uploading aren't really images despite their extensions.

Regarding GIFs - you must use ImageMagick if you want to upload animated GIFs, as it's not possible for Craft to reconstruct an animated gif using the GD library.

Comment: Thanks. Spend the week trying like everything on my ubuntu server. Updating my broken ImageMagick extension fixed everything.

Comment: I built an Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS server with PHP7 that has ImageMagick installed and yet an empty magic file as mentioned ages ago [in this Ubuntu bug report](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/228062). Haven't resolved yet, but I figure it's worth a clue if someone else winds up in the same predicament.