# Can't upload GIF files

Tags: assets, image

I have the same error in [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/the-file-does-not-appear-to-be-an-image-bug).

Craft info says i have installed the ImageMagick extension successfully  and even use `'imageDriver' => 'imagick'` in config file. But still cant upload GIF files.

Comment: Are they animated GIFs or just static GIFs? Do other file formats (JPG, PNG, etc.) upload fine? You're getting the exact same error message as the linked to thread?

Comment: @BradBell They are animated gif's. Yes other assets are uploading fine. Yes the exact same message.

Comment: What version of Imagick/fileinfo are you running? The linked thread suggests that updating it fixed the issue for them.

Comment: It's module version is 3.1.2 and version is ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2017-05-26 Q16

Comment: The module is fairly old. https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=imagick.  And the library is on 7.x now. Try updating? https://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php

Comment: Ok thanks @BradBell i had to manually update both module and library. Here are a good tutorial on how to update on older configs [link](https://www.enovate.co.uk/blog/2015/12/16/how-to-install-imagemagick-from-source-on-ubuntu-14.04)

Comment: Glad you're all sorted, @orionlogic. Would you mind adding that as an official answer in case it helps someone else in the future? :)

Comment: I know that's the old question, but I have a problem with uploading gifs. I mean, if I want to upload it directly to the assets, there is no problem, but if I want to upload this while creating entries, I got this message: Upload failed. The error message was: “The file “/app/storage/runtime/temp/name.gif” does not appear to be an image.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved, as @bradbell said the version for ImageMagick module and library was old and need to be update. You can check the latest relase from here: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php

From some servers apt-get update won't really update the package. So you need yo install manually. There is a great [how to article](https://www.enovate.co.uk/blog/2015/12/16/how-to-install-imagemagick-from-source-on-ubuntu-14.04) regarding this